# Wifi disconnects but signal is strong

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking

After formating and reinstalling my desktop with Win XP Home Edition I installed the newest software for my wifi USB adapter TP-Link TL-WN721N. Everything went fine and the signal was strong. I connected to the internet to download all the necessary things and about 15 seconds of browsing later my connection stopped working. The signal was still strong, I was still connected to the network but there were no packets sent either up or down and no webpages were loading anymore. This problem persisted after reconnecting to the network, restarting the computer and even reinstalling the windows anew. Other computers that are connected to this wifi network have no problems.

I tried several solutions I found on Google but to no avail. Ping command fails to contact any server, ipconfig/release works but ipconfig/renew is unable to contact DHCP server. ipconfig/flushdns works but is of no help.

Comment: I would recommend taking your USB wifi adapter and plugging it into another machine and see if the problem persists. If you have the same issues with it on another machine, you might be looking at a bad wifi adapter

Comment: I would roll back the driver for the device.  Although if you reinstalled Windows and it still does not work I am going to guess the device is not working.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think about trying it on another machine... I plugged it into my laptop (running Win 8) and it works flawlessly there. But the system calls it Atheros AR9271 for some reason...

Answer (score 1):

There are some tricks that you can try:

1. You can use Device Manager to change the power management settings
   for a network adapter. To disable this setting in Device Manager,
   expand Network Adapters, right-click the adapter, click Properties,
   click the Power Management tab, and then clear the **Allow the
   computer to turn off this device to save power** check box.
2. Uninstall
   and reinstall with the newest drivers. Another similar option is uninstall the driver and let the windows install automatically the driver.
3. Try to plug the adapter in a USB3 port (if
   you have one in your computer)
4. In your router, verify in the security session if the option **Group Key Update Period** is 0 (zero).
5. Go to Advanced Power Settings found in Control Panel\Hardware and Edit Plan Settings. Switched the plan to use a High Performance plan and adjust the option **Wireless Adapter Power Savings Mode** to Maximum Performance. Also disable the option **USB Selective Suspend**.
6. Try to change the power supply of your computer (if is a desktop computer) and verify if the problem continues.
7. If you are using a USB adapter, try to use a PCI Express Wifi adapter.